# How to implement API authentication for Rails app with Authlogic

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, authlogic

I have a Rails app with an iOS mobile client.

So far, I've had the iPhone client send HTTP requests to the normal URLs. I want to replace this with a proper API. I'm on Rails 3, and I'm using Authlogic for authentication.

I have watched the railscasts on versioned apis and [securing APIs](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api). But since I'm already using authlogic for authentication, I think reimplementing token creation would be unnecessary?

I created the API just as Ryan Bates suggests in [this episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast) with a controller under app/controllers/api/v1/. I have corresponding views with RABL in views/api/v1.

My controller is

```
module Api
  module V1
    class RecordsController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      def index
        status = RecordStatus.where("name = ?", "processed").first
        @records = current_user.records.where("record_status_id = ?", status.id)
      end

      def show
        @record = Record.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, I've read a lot on the different options to implement (including a bunch of answers on SO) and I'm just really stumped as to what's the best way for me to implement authentication, securely. Should I go to oauth? Can I do it with authlogic? Which option would make it easy to use from the iOS side? Which option is easiest to implement?

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the single access token stuff that's in authlogic already?

http://rubydoc.info/gems/authlogic/Authlogic/Session/Params

Comment: But I do need persistence. Once the user logs in to the iPhone app once, they need to remain logged in. Also, having the token out in the open isn't that secure is it? That was one of the solutions in the railscasts. I wasn't sure about using it.

Comment: My reading of that is that it is persistant, you just have to pass it every time.  How you secure having your app have that... that's up to you.  Make them login, then set a new token, use that for the session,  then forget it... I dunno...